# A Shortest Path Algorithm With Minimum Number Of Nodes Traversed

Tags: graph, shortest-path, dijkstra

I am looking for a Dijkstra's algorithm implementation, that also takes into consideration the number of nodes traversed.

What I mean is, a typical Dijkstra's algorithm, takes into consideration the weight of the edges connecting the nodes, while calculating the shortest route from node A to node B. I want to insert another parameter into this. I want the algorithm to give some weightage to the number of nodes traversed, as well.

So that the shortest route computed from A to B, under certain values, may not necessarily be the Shortest Route, but the route with the least number of nodes traversed.

Any thoughts on this?

Cheers,
RD

Edit :
My apologies. I should have explained better. So, lets say, the shortest route from
(A, B) is A -> C -> D -> E -> F -> B covering a total of 10 units
But I want the algorithm to come up with the route A -> M -> N -> B covering a total of 12 units.
So, what I want, is to be able to give some weightage to the number of nodes as well, not just the distance of the connected nodes.

Comment: You can modify the weights, increasing each edge by a constant, which penalizes using more edges (equiv. more nodes) in a path.  Basically you need to articulate more clearly what objective function is being minimized.

Comment: You've given conditions that are too vague to really be helpful. This is an ill-formed question. One obvious comment: if the nature of taking the number of nodes traversed into account is additive, then consider adding a uniform amount to your weights to make each node traversal take a uniform amount longer.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying: The route you return MUST be the shortest number of nodes traversed, but in addition, of all solutions that are the shortest number of nodes traversed, you want the least edge weight?

Comment: @hardmath : If I uniformly increase all edges, then there is no change in the shortest path computed.

Comment: @Kaganar : I hope after the edit, my question is clearer.

Comment: @Jeremy : I am trying to get an algorithm, which returns the shortest route, alongwith the least number of nodes. Something that can take both into consideration.

Comment: @Rohitesh: Your reply to me is incorrect.  See the example I posted as an Answer, showing how adding a constant to all edges can give preference to a path with fewer nodes (equiv. fewer edges).

Answer (score 6):

Let me demonstrate that adding a constant value to all edges can change which route is "shortest" (least total weight of edges).

Here's the original graph (a triangle):

```
A-------B
 \  5  /
2 \   / 2
   \ /
    C
```

Shortest path from A to B is via C.  Now add constant 2 to all edges.  The shortest path becomes instead the single step from A directly to B (owing to "penalty" we've introduced for using additional edges).

Note that the number of edges used is (excluding the node you start from) the same as the number of nodes visited.

Comment: Thank you. Its working. But now I have another problem. Updating all edges, after each iteration, is increasing the time taken for the computation, by approximately 60-80 times (that's 6000% to 8000%), which is unacceptable. I have 700+ nodes, where each node has an average of 3 connection to other nodes. Any suggestions on improving on the performance?

Comment: Why do you need to update all the edges after each iteration?The updation would be only one time change, Isn't it? or you need not do the updation as separate operation, While calculating the distance between two nodes add the node cost to it.

Comment: What @Praveen said... do the update once on actual edge weights, or just include the constant in the Dijkstra steps, so that you record minimum total weight distances to new nodes with one more copy of that constant.  Choosing the constant is your control over balancing the minimum (original) edge weight vs. minimizing the number of nodes visited (edges traversed).  A zero constant corresponds to the original minimum distance problem.  For a sufficiently large constant you effectively minimize number of nodes visited as in the limit all edges have equal weights.

Answer (score 2):

The way you can do that is adapt the weights of the edges to always be 1, so that you traverse 5 nodes, and you've gone a distance of "5".  The algorithm would be the same at that point, optimizing for number of nodes traversed rather than distance traveled.

If you want some sort of hybrid, you need to determine how much importance to give to traversing a node and the distance.  The weight used in calculations should look something like:

`weight = node_importance * 1 + (1 - node_importance) * distance`

Where node_importance would be a percentage which gauges how much distance is a factor and how much minimum node traversal is important.  Though you may have to normalize the distances to be an average of 1.

Comment: Agreed. Only, I would write the formula as `weight = node_modifier + distance` (which is proportionally the same as yours, just simpler)

Comment: So, what you mean is, that I should increment ALL edges? But the edges are stored as an array. So, I should increment each and every value, at each iteration of the traversal?

Comment: @pjotr : Could you help me with this? I couldn't really understand, what you are suggesting.

Comment: @user377349 I'm suggesting the same as hardmath and Kaganar in comments to your question. You add a constant to the length of each edge. Size of this constant (relative to the edge lengths) will determine, how "heavy" is the node count criterion.
For your example, you may choose 2 as the value for this constant - that will give you 20 as distance for the acdefb path and 18 for the amnb path

Comment: @user377349, the algorithm tries to optimize the edge weight, so if you make all edge weights 1, distance is not even considered.  It would try to avoid traversing too many nodes instead.  What I'm suggesting is some sort of hybrid.  Distance is important, but so are the number of nodes traversed.  To do that, you need to assign weights according to the formula above rather than simply assign the weight to the distance (would be the same as node_importance = 0).

Comment: Thank you @Neil. It is working now. But now I have another problem. Updating all edges, after each iteration, is increasing the time taken for the computation, by approximately 60-80 times (that's 6000% to 8000%), which is unacceptable. I have 700+ nodes, where each node has an average of 3 connection to other nodes. Any suggestions on improving on the performance?

Comment: @Rohitesh, the edge weight doesn't change.  If it were the same problem, but you were measuring distance, you wouldn't have to recalculate distance everytime would you?  Same thing here.  Place your points, assign weights according to my formula and let the algorithm do the work.  I'm afraid you haven't quite grasped what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb here, but have you tried the A* algorithm? I may have understood your question wrong, but it seems like A* would be a good starting point for what you want to do.

Check out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

Some pseudo code there to help you out too :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @graysheep. But A* is not what I am really looking for, on this. But thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood the question correctly then its best analogy would be that used to find the best network path.

In network communication a path may not only be selected because it is shortest but has many hop counts(node), thus may lead to distortion, interference and noise due to node connection.

So the best path calculation contains the minimizing the function of variables as in your case Distance and Hop Count(nodes).

You have to derive a functional equation that could relate the distance and node counts with quality.

so something as suppose
`1 hop count change = 5 unit distance` (which means the impact is same for 5unit distace or 1 node change)

so to minimize the loss you can use it in the linear equation.
`minimize(distance + hopcount);`
where hopcount can be expressed as distance.

Comment: Thank you Praveen. I am now using the same logic, and it is working. However, I am facing some performance issues, which I am trying to smoothen out.