# How to implement A* with minimum number of nodes on path?

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, shortest-path, path-finding, a-star

I have implemented my A* algorithm such that it finds the shortest path to goal, given that it can move only to neighboring/adjacent cells. (Assume nodes are cells in a grid). So there's 8 surrounding cells it can move.

```
OOO
O*O
OOO
```

This works and finds the shortest path but what if I only want the nodes that are about 20-40 cells apart, and less if needed (say a door is only one cell away.  How would I go about this without post processing the path?
So something like this?

```
XXXXOXOXOXXXX
XXXXXOOOXXXXX
OOOOOO*OOOOOO
XXXXXOOOXXXXX
XXXXOXOXOXXXX
```

Where O are the 'neighbors and X's are not.

```
def search(grid,start,goal):

    dist = {}
    visited = {}
    predecessors= {}
    hscore = {}
    gscore = {}
    gscore[start] = 0
    hscore[start] = gscore[start] + heuristic(start,goal)
    pq = PriorityQueue()
    pq.put((hscore[start],start))
    while not pq.empty():
        current = pq.get()
        if current[1] == goal:
            return build_path(predecessors,goal)
        visited[current[1]] = current[1]
        max_dist = 0


        succs = successors(grid,current[1],goal,pixels=90)
        for successor in succs:
            if visited.get(successor[0],None) != None:
                continue
            grid.grid[successor[0]] = (0,255,0)



            g = gscore[current[1]] + 1



            in_pq = successor[0] in pq
            if (not in_pq or g < gscore[successor[0]] ):
                predecessors[successor[0]] = current[1]
                gscore[successor[0]] = g
                hscore[successor[0]] = g + heuristic(successor[0],goal)


                max_dist = dist
                if not in_pq:
                    pq.put((hscore[successor[0]],successor[0]))
    return []
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996808/a-shortest-path-algorithm-with-minimum-number-of-nodes-traversed

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate. While thats minimum traversed, I want the minimum to make that makes the path work. Think of it as removing "extra" nodes on path. We can get from point A to B in 10 nodes, or we can get there in 1 node, I want to get there in 1 node.

Comment: When you say you have implemented it, can we see the code?

Comment: I added the search function. I've only implemented the basic A* traversing one node at a time.

Comment: I don't quite get your problem specification. But it sounds like you just need to add more edges to the graph (probably through the `successors`?).